# reusing code in function and running it with loop

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

In variable.php , the page use to display any attributes related to a product. I want some changes in code but not for all pages, so i think only point it to create a function of variable.php, and call it within custom loop. 
My question is how do i make a function out of variable.php, put all variable.php in

```
function{
 code from [variable][1].php
}
```

After making a function, how do i insert it in a loop, so it prints with every product?

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);
$featured_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
        $featured_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <ul>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></a></li>
        </ul>

        <?php

    }
    wp_resetpostdata();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up the function like this in your functions.php

```
function my_function(){
   //your function in here
   include(TEMPLATEPATH . '[variable][1].php');
}
```

And then in your loop you would call it like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
        $featured_query->the_post();

        ?>
        <ul>
        <li><?php my_function(); ?></li>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></a></li>
        </ul>

        <?php

    }
    wp_resetpostdata();
}
```